# How to put variable in codeigniter $row->data

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to make the variable more simple by just change its title.. here's my code

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row) : ?>
            <?php $id = $this->uri->segment(1);?>
            <?php if($id === "product"){ $id === 'product'; }elseif($id === 'pabrikan'){ $id === 'pabrikan';}   ?>
            <?php $productTitle = str_replace(' ' ,'-', $row->.$id._title);?><?php endforeach;?>
```

However I want to make the $productTitle can be dynamic by just take from $id.
How can $row->product_title can be $row->$id_title the $id is taken from segment 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $var_title=$id.'_title';
    $productTitle=$row[$var_title];
    .....
```

Comment: @nady saptra Welcome dude , mark the answer as accepted